# Nginx rewrite url with parameters without changing url

Tags: nginx, url-rewriting, nginx-reverse-proxy

I am using Nginx as a proxy server and want use certain user friendly url with parameters to proxypass/rewrite to another url with the respective parameters.

I am expecting that from this url:
[www.mydomain.com/report/bill/p1/p2/p3/p4](http://www.mydomain.com/report/bill/p1/p2/p3/p4)
to use this
http://192.168.0.1:9002/reports/servlet?param1=$p1&param2=$p2&param3=$p3&param4=$p4

I tried the below, with no success

```
location /report/bill/ {
    rewrite ^/report/bill/(.*)$ $1 break;
    rewrite ^/report/bill/(.*)/(.*)$ $2 break;
    rewrite ^/report/bill/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)$ $3 break;
    rewrite ^/report/bill/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)$/(.*)$ $4 break;
    proxy_pass http://192.168.0.1:9002/reports/servlet?param1=$1&param2=$2&param3=$3&param4=$4;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have misunderstood how `rewrite` works.

However, `rewrite` is capable of doing everything you want in a single statement:

```
rewrite ^/report/bill/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)$ /reports/servlet?param1=$1&param2=$2&param3=$3&param4=$4 break;
proxy_pass http://192.168.0.1:9002;
```

I probably wouldn't use `(.*)` for the capture, as it captures everything including `/`s. You could use `([^/]+)` which would capture everything between two `/`s.